# How to set ViewBinding in buildgradle.kts?

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-viewbinding

I could easily set `dataBinding` in `buld.gradle.kts` by doing:

```
dataBinding {
    isEnabled = true
}
```

But I could not seem to find the equivalent for `viewBinding`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `viewBinding.isEnabled` is going to be deprecated, using buildFeatures would be better.

```
android {
...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to be on Android Studio 3.6 and add :

```
android {
  viewBinding.isEnabled = true
}
```

Update :

You also need your gradle plugin to be at least on `3.6.0`

Comment: Ive tried this one but it doesnt work. Im also using 3.6.

Comment: So apparently, it was my android gradle plugin which needed the update to get access of the viewBinding. I'll mark this as correct if you update your answer to include the updating of the android gradle plugin version. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
  viewBinding {
    isEnabled = true
  }
}
```

With Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.0 or newer, with Android Studio 3.6.0 or newer, and with Android Build Tools newer than 3.6.0 (`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0")`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for doing this. Both worked for me

// First

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }    
}
```

// Second

```
android {
    viewBinding.isEnabled = true
}
```